# Reshape data with multiple header rows in R

Tags: r, excel, tidyr, readr, readxl

```
                Julie                           Joe                
                Measurement 1   Measurement 2   Measurement 1   Measurement 2
Part Number 1   33              32              33              31
Part Number 2   34              31              33              32
Part Number 3   33              31              30              31
```

How do I get this *messy* Excel table into a tidy format for use in R? I can utilize readr functions like `spread()` and `gather()` but this seems to need a higher level of sophistication. Here's my best reconstruction of the Excel data frame for you to mess with. Please modify it at will to better make any point.

```
library(tidyverse)
messy <- data.frame(
  " " = c(" ", "Part Number 1", "Part Number 2", "Part Number 3"), 
  Julie = c("Measurement 1", 33, 34, 33),
  Julie = c("Measurement 2", 32, 31, 31),
  Joe = c("Measurement 1", 33, 33, 30),
  Joe = c("Measurement 2", 31, 32, 31))
```

I'm open to trying the dev versions of readr or tidyr. The new `pack()`, `unpack()` etc. functions seem to be useful. Also, it appears other SO attempts/solutions aren't quite what I'm looking for [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54269639/reshaping-longitudinal-value-to-wide-for-data-with-multiple-rows-per-subject), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139288/combining-multiple-rows-into-one-row-with-multiple-columns-of-data-r), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32732728/gather-multiple-date-value-columns-using-tidyr).

Comment: I actually asked a similar question recently. Here is the response I got and it worked great for my data. I had to make a few modification since I had ~10 different categories on the top that each spread over 4 years. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467814/reshape-dataframe-that-has-years-in-column-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part is getting the correct column names and then performing `gather` and `separate`, which it sounds like you're already familiar with. Normally I do not like selecting rows by number, but in this case I think it makes sense if you're reliably reading the data from Excel in this way.

note: If a person's name has a `.` in it, the last step would fail.

```r
library(tidyverse)

less_messy <- messy %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  set_names(c("Part",
             paste(names(.)[2:ncol(.)],
                   .[1, 2:ncol(.)],
                   sep = "-"))) %>%
  `[`(2:nrow(.), ) %>%
  gather("key", "value", contains("Measurement")) %>%
  separate("key", c("person", "measurement"), sep = "-") %>%
  mutate_at("person", ~ stringr::str_replace(.x, "\\..*",""))

less_messy
#>             Part person   measurement value
#> 1  Part Number 1  Julie Measurement 1    33
#> 2  Part Number 2  Julie Measurement 1    34
#> 3  Part Number 3  Julie Measurement 1    33
#> 4  Part Number 1  Julie Measurement 2    32
#> 5  Part Number 2  Julie Measurement 2    31
#> 6  Part Number 3  Julie Measurement 2    31
#> 7  Part Number 1    Joe Measurement 1    33
#> 8  Part Number 2    Joe Measurement 1    33
#> 9  Part Number 3    Joe Measurement 1    30
#> 10 Part Number 1    Joe Measurement 2    31
#> 11 Part Number 2    Joe Measurement 2    32
#> 12 Part Number 3    Joe Measurement 2    31
```

### data

changed marginally because I noticed a discrepancy between what you showed and your code for the measurement numbers:

```r
messy <- data.frame(
  " " = c(" ", "Part Number 1", "Part Number 2", "Part Number 3"), 
  Julie = c("Measurement 1", 33, 34, 33),
  Julie = c("Measurement 2", 32, 31, 31),
  Joe = c("Measurement 1", 33, 33, 30),
  Joe = c("Measurement 2", 31, 32, 31))
```

Comment: What is `\`[\`(2:nrow(.), )` this line doing? I've never seen such a thing in my several years playing in the tidyverse. I probably need to read a book on base R at some point. Best I can guess is `\`[\`` is short hand for `[]`?

Comment: It's just normal subsetting. It looks funny because I need to quote it with back ticks to include it in the pipe steps. E.g., `mtcars[1:5, ]` and `\`[\`(mtcars, 1:5, )` are the same.

Comment: Oah so `\`[\`(2:nrow(.), )` is functionally equivalent to `.[2:nrow(.), ]` in your example? I just never saw that notation `\`[\`` before. Searching `R \`[\`` doesn't yield much either. Thanks